# Oracle SQL to compare 2 rows and return values

Tags: sql, oracle

My data is in below format

```
Test ID | DailyMonthly
    =======================
    12345   | Daily
    12345   | Monthly
    23456   | Daily
    23456   | Daily
    09876   | Monthly
    09876   | Monthly
```

I want to return results as,

```
12345 - Both
23456 - Daily
09876 - Monthly
```

How can this be achieved? Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: I tried row_number() partition by and case statements but not quite getting what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet another option is using distinct `count` as following:

```
SELECT "Test ID",
       CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT "DailyMonthly") > 1 THEN 'Both'
            ELSE MIN("DailyMonthly")
       END AS Result
FROM data
GROUP BY "Test ID"
ORDER BY "Test ID"
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT TestID,
         CASE WHEN COUNT (TestID) > 1 THEN 'Both' ELSE DailyMonthly END
             AS DailyMonthly
    FROM (  SELECT TestID, DailyMonthly
              FROM data_
          GROUP BY TestID, DailyMonthly)
ORDER BY DailyMonthly
```